# Can't drop pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I need to slice into several tables based on values and save into several .csv files. This method seems to work, however it creates a column (first one) that I cannot drop (instead drops 2nd column). Could someone tell me why it is there and how can I get rid of it? Thank you. Here is the code:

```
new_d['Supplier'] = new_d.apply(lambda row: determine_supplier(row), axis = 1)
new_d.sort_values(by = ['Supplier'], inplace = True)
new_d.set_index(keys = ['Supplier'], drop = False, inplace = True)
suppliers = new_d['Supplier'].unique().tolist()
for supplier in suppliers:
  po = new_d.loc[new_d.Supplier == supplier] #the problem is here?
  po = po.drop(po.columns[[0]], axis = 1) # can't drop
  po.to_csv(path_or_buf = r'PO\\' + supplier + '_PO.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First column in `DataFrame` is called `index`.

You need parameter `index=False` in [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for omit it:

```
po.to_csv(path_or_buf = r'PO\\'+ supplier+'_PO.csv',index=False)
```

Or better:

Instead:

```
for supplier in suppliers:
  po = new_d.loc[new_d.Supplier == supplier] #the problem is here?
  po = po.drop(po.columns[[0]], axis = 1) # can't drop
  po.to_csv(path_or_buf = r'PO\\' + supplier + '_PO.csv')
```

use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for [looping](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups):

```
for supplier, po in new_d.groupby('Supplier'):
    po.to_csv(r'PO\\'+ supplier +'_PO.csv',index=False)
```